# Adding occurrences in a string which starts with a pattern and ends with a pattern to a list

Tags: python

I have a string that looks like this:

```
"var schema = {\r\n    \"type\": \"object\",\r\n    \"properties\": {\r\n    \"content\": \"string\",\r\n    \"created_at\": \"integer\",\r\n    \"id\": \"string\"\r\n},\r\n\"required\": [\"content\", \"created_at\", \"id\"]\r\n};\r\n \r\nvar data = JSON.parse(responseBody);\r\n \r\nvar result = tv4.validateResult(data, schema);\r\ntests[\"Status code: \" + responseCode.code] = responseCode.code === 200;\r\ntests[\"Valid schema\"] = result.valid;",
```

What I need is to find all occurrences that starts with (tests[") and ends with nest ("]")
and append them to a list, this should give my a list looking like this.

```
['tests[\"Status code: \" + responseCode.code]', 'tests[\"Valid schema\"]']
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re
result = re.findall(r'tests\["[^]]+?\]', my_string)
```